# Segfault on reading large file with ifstream on 64 bit Debian

Tags: c++, 64-bit, g++, ifstream

I am trying to read a large file (~5GB) using ifstream in C++.
Since I'm on a 64bit OS, I thought this shouldn't be a problem.
Still, I get a segfault. Everything runs fine with smaller files,
so I'm pretty sure that is where the problem is.

I'm using g++ (4.4.5-8) and libstdc++6 (4.4.5-8).

Thanks.

The code looks like this:

```
void load (const std::string &path, int _dim, int skip = 0, int gap = 0) {
    std::ifstream is(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    BOOST_VERIFY(is);
    is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = is.tellg();
    size -= skip;
    long int line = sizeof(float) * _dim + gap;
    BOOST_VERIFY(size % line == 0);
    long int _N =  size / line;
    reset(_dim, _N);
    is.seekg(skip, std::ios::beg);
    char *off = dims;
    for (long int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        is.read(off, sizeof(T) * dim);
        is.seekg(gap, std::ios::cur);
        off += stride;
    }
    BOOST_VERIFY(is);
}
```

The segfault is in the `is.read` line for i=187664.
T is float and I'm reading dim=1000 floats at a time.
When the segfault occures, i * stride is way smaller than size, so I'm not running past the end of the file.

dims is allocated here

```
void reset (int _dim, int _N)
{
    BOOST_ASSERT((ALIGN % sizeof(T)) == 0);
    dim = _dim;
    N = _N;
    stride = dim * sizeof(T) + ALIGN - 1;
    stride = stride / ALIGN * ALIGN;
    if (dims != NULL) delete[] dims;
    dims = (char *)memalign(ALIGN, N * stride); 
    std::fill(dims, dims + N * stride, 0);
}
```

Comment: How are you reading the file and where exactly is the segmentation fault?

Comment: Post some relevant code.

Comment: What is `dims`? how is it allocated? Are you sure you're not running past its end?

Comment: Is "long int" any different from "int"?

Comment: sizeof in gdb told me that int is 4 bytes (which surprised me) and long int is 8.

Comment: What is T? Template type? What is it when the code fails?

Comment: I would guess that the memory pointed to by `dims` is too small. The code doesn't contain any error checking at all although this shouldn't really cause any segmentation fault.

Comment: You're right, the memalign should be checked. I checked it, it succeeds.

Comment: Hang on - didn't you just say that `int` is a 32 bit number while `size` is bigger than 2^^31? Wouldn't this mean that you are essentially guaranteed to allocate to little memory (assuming `stride` is also `int`. What is `memalign()` and why not just `new T[x]`? BTW, the check whether `dims` is not `NULL` prior to deleting is unnecessary.

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you so much :)
Btw, that is not my code, but some code from a research paper.
Unfortunately, I can not really afford to make everything pretty.
Thank you for pointing me to the place where the overflow happened!

Answer (score 1):

I don't  know if this is the bug, but this code looks very C like and plenty of opportunity to leak. Any way try changing

```
void reset (int _dim, int _N)
```

to

```
void reset (size_t dim, size_t _N)
//I would avoid using leading underscores that is usually used to identify elements of the standard library.
```

When you are dealing with the size or index of something in memory ALWAYS use size_t, it is guaranteed to be able to hold the maximum size of an object including arrays.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, of course. This wasn't the problem, though.

Comment: @AndreasMueller Oh ok, another quick point, are you sure that memalign is capable of deliver such amounts? have you tried that same but using good old new? (that will throw a std::bad_alloc if i can'ta alloc that much). Also is this data structured or just a flat file, I ask because using read() is a bit the old way as an opposed to creating a container of types and populating it with entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `_ftelli64` etc... to have the right size of your file, and to use `long long` (or `_int64`) variables to manage it. But it's C library. I don't find how to use `ifstream` with so big file (actualy > 2Go). Did you find the way ?

PS : In your case `size_t` is fine, but I'm not sure that's OK with 32-bit software. I'm sure it's OK with 64-bit.

```
int main()
{
    string name="tstFile.bin";
    FILE *inFile,*inFile2;
    fopen_s(&inFile,name.c_str(),"rb"); 
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"\r\n***error -> File not found\r\n";
        return 0;
    }

    _fseeki64 (inFile,0L,SEEK_END);
    long long fileLength = _ftelli64(inFile); 
    _fseeki64 (inFile,0L,SEEK_SET);

    cout<<"file lg : "<<fileLength<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The solution is in one of the comments.